# Deferring inference of generic type parameter to runtime in C#

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

In a C# .NET 6 application, I'm using the Microsoft Word mail-merge implementation provided by Aspose.Words. One of the way in which a data source can be provided for the mail-merge is through a collection class that implements Aspose's IMailMergeDataSource interface, with implementations for methods MoveNext() and GetValue() methods. Given that the data sets driving the merges are in the form of IEnumerator, I'm using reflection to enable the collection to be constructed transparently so that the caller can just supply the IEnumerable collection without having to know about IMailMergeDataSource. The class is MergeDataSource, and the constructor takes a parameter of type IEnumerable.

The interface also provides a method called GetChildDataSource that's supposed to return another IMailMergeDataSource instance for any properties of T that are themselves IEnumerables of some type: IEnumerable, IEnumerable, etc. These are used for iteration over child data within sections of the overall merge template.

The lookup tables tell the class how, for each merge field name or child data region used in the merge template, what the corresponding Func<T, object> is to get the necessary value from the current T item in the enumerable.

For example, suppose the mail-merge is generating a list for each student of the courses that student is taking. So I have an object, Students, of type IEnumerator. Student.Courses is, for each student, an IEnumerable of the student's courses. The merge template is a letter to a student, with merge fields such as <> and <, with a list of the student's courses embedded in the middle of general information for the student in a <> region. The merge will run through this for each student.

My problem is in GetChildDataSource, with the return statement

```
return new MergeDataSource(mapping!(_enumerator.Current));
```

Here, _enumerator.Current is going to be pointing to an IEnumerable for some T2. But the compiler doesn't know what T2 is going to be, it'll be determinable at runtime. Visual Studio shows me "Using the generic type 'MergeDataSource' requires 1 type arguments". Is there a way to make this work? If it can be done using reflection, great, as long as it isn't an ordeal!

All the code:

```
public class MergeDataSource<T> : IMailMergeDataSource where T : class
{
    private IEnumerable<T> _items;
    private IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;
    private IDictionary<string, Func<T, object?>> _fieldMappingLookup = new Dictionary<string, Func<T, object?>>();
    private IDictionary<string, Func<T, object?>> _childMappingLookup = new Dictionary<string, Func<T, object?>>();

    public MergeDataSource(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        _items = items;
        _enumerator = items.GetEnumerator();

        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IEnumerable)))
            {
                _childMappingLookup.Add(prop.Name, (T item) => prop.GetValue(item));
            }
            else
            {
                _fieldMappingLookup.Add(prop.Name, (T item) => prop.GetValue(item));
            }
        }

    }

    public string TableName => typeof(T).Name;

    public IMailMergeDataSource GetChildDataSource(string tableName)
    {
        if (_childMappingLookup.Keys.Contains(tableName))
        {
            var mapping = _childMappingLookup[tableName];
            return new MergeDataSource(mapping!(_enumerator.Current));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public bool GetValue(string fieldName, out object? fieldValue)
    {
        if (_fieldMappingLookup.Keys.Contains(fieldName))
        {
            var mapping = _fieldMappingLookup[fieldName];
            fieldValue = mapping!(_enumerator.Current);
            return true;
        }
        fieldValue = null;
        return false;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return _enumerator.MoveNext();
    }

}
```

Comment: Generics **MUST** resolve at compile time. End of story. Maybe a cast would help, but also a lot of interop code is COM based and may need to rely on `dynamic`.